# How to apply layer style on the same layer on all frames at a same time

Tags: adobe-photoshop, animation, gif

I am working on a gif where i have used a  cloud image.

I now want to apply effects on the single layer .i.e cloud image on all the frames at the same time.

I have tried selecting the no. of required frames and right click on the layer then paste layer style.

But the style is applied to only one frame. There are around 80 frames. Is there a way to apply the effect on all frames at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to convert all layers to smart object or group them, after that apply the effects to smart objects or the whole group. Other than that I don't have anything in my mind.